# UITableVIewCell Autolayout images with the same width/height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I took a project and need to add 3 images under the "desciption" section.

They need to have same width/height (square) create dynamically.
I have not managed to do I set constants.

Can you help me to add these 3 images to the cell content, please ?

Thanks a lot for your future help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are those static cells? i suggest u to use xib!!!

Comment: I tried to make a xib but I can't call it from .m; it's use the same cell as in screen capture (I changed in cellForRowAtIndexPath the path for cell but nothing). How can I call tje cell with xib and remove that structure ?

Comment: show us the code of how u called the xib

Comment: In storyboard I have this approach (question edited and added in question body).

Comment: Code used to call the cell :    static NSString *identifier = @"facebookFriend";
    FacebookFriendTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FacebookFriendTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

Comment: In storyboard I have to remove the UITableView and add a normal uitable ?

Comment: you need to remove the table cell, just keep plain tableview!!!! and load the xib!!!

Comment: I'm trying right now ...

Comment: it works ! thanks a lot for your help !